# Rank Nullity Theorem not working?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

In class we were given the question:

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional vector space (with dimension $n$), and $f\in X^*.$ What can the dimension of the null space of $f$ be?.

In this unit we're only considering the dual space mapping into $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. So, using Rank-Nullity Theorem, I got

$$\mathcal{N}(f)=n-1\text{ unless }f\equiv0\text{ in which case }\mathcal{N}(f)=n.$$

However, my lecturer constructed the following arugment,

Let $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ be a basis for $X$.

For any $x\in X$ we can write,
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i e_i.$$
Now, for any $k=1,2,...,n$ let
$$\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_k,0,0,...,0).$$
We can define $f_\alpha\in X^*$ like so,
\begin{align*}
    f_\alpha (x):=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i\alpha_i=\sum_{i=1}^k \xi_i\alpha_i+\sum_{i=k+1}^n \xi_i 0=\sum_{i=1}^k \xi_i\alpha_i.
\end{align*}
So, $\operatorname{span}\{e_{k+1},e_{k+2},...,e_n\}=\mathcal{N}(f_\alpha)$.

Therefore,
$$\dim(\mathcal{N}(f_\alpha))=n-k.$$

While I understand this argument, I'm not quite sure why how it squares with the Rank Nullity Theorem.

Edit: Thanks so much for the responses. Also, just have to add, my lecturer is awesome.

Comment: Your answer $$\mathcal{N}(f)=n-1\text{ unless }f\equiv0\text{ in which case }\mathcal{N}(f)=n.$$ is exactly correct. Equivalently, the image of $f$ is either $\{0\}$ or the entire base field. This is because the dimension of the base field, considered as a vector space over itself, is $1$, so there are only two possibilities for the dimension of the image of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you have $\mathrm{span}\{e_{k+1},\cdots,e_n\}\color{Red}{\subset} N(f_{\alpha})$. It's not equality.

Imagine, for instance, $k=n$. Then $f_{\alpha}(X)=\alpha\cdot x$ has a kernel, namely the orthogonal complement of $\alpha$.

Indeed, if you pick any nonzero coordinate $\alpha_i$ of $\alpha$, then to construct an arbitrary $x\in N(f_{\alpha})$ you can let the coordinates $x_j$ be anything for $j\ne i$ and then solve for $x_i$ as appropriate. That's $n-1$ degrees of freedom for the null space.

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes sense